# Scraping a table using Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape this product table,

http://www.dropforyou.com/search2.php?mode=search&posted_data%5Bcategoryid%5D=2&posted_data%5Bsearch_in_subcategories%5D=on

I need the product id, the quantity and the price.

Since the site uses cookies and a post form I am grabbing the site with CURL. Which works fine. I am then loading that into simple html dom with $html = str_get_html($content);

I have been able to load all the table values into an array, however I can't label them. They just come in as 0,1,2 and I can't tell what's what.

I tried using a different method posted here on stackoverflow, however it gives me Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in

My working code that isn't labeled

```
$content = curlscraper($urltoscrape);

$html = str_get_html($content);

$tds = $html->find('table',2)->find('td');

$num = NULL;
foreach($tds as $td)
{
    $num[] = $td->plaintext;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump ($num);
echo '</pre>';
```

The code I found on Stackoverflow that just gives me Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in

```
$content = curlscraper($urltoscrape);

$html = str_get_html($content);

foreach($html->find('tr',2) as $page)
{
$item['sku'] = $page->find('td',0)->plaintext;
$item['product'] = $page->find('td',1)->plaintext;
$item['Qty'] = $page->find('td',2)->plaintext;
$item['description'] = $page->find('td',3)->plaintext;
$item['price'] = $page->find('td',4)->plaintext;

$table[] = $item;
}

print_r($table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initialize variable for your foreach function and then use your code. But you don't say which line created that error?

```
 $line = $html->find('tr',2);

 foreach($line as $page)
{
//var_dump($page) //You can check array
$item['sku'] = $page->find('td',0)->plaintext;
$item['product'] = $page->find('td',1)->plaintext;
$item['Qty'] = $page->find('td',2)->plaintext;
$item['description'] = $page->find('td',3)->plaintext;
$item['price'] = $page->find('td',4)->plaintext;

$table[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: $item['sku'] = $page->find('td',0)->plaintext;